# JSX not rendering to DOM

Tags: reactjs

Nothing is being rendered to the DOM. It might be something to do with the multiple map loops though this is just a guess. Had a search around but couldn't find anything of use for my problem.

I have changed all forEach loops to map. I have console logged everything from each map and all outputs are correct. I have even tried with a simple "Hello, world!" using h1 tag but to no avail.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import FilterWidget from "./FilterWidget";
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import ChartWidget from "./ChartWidget";
import "./ProjectsWidget.css";
import { BarChart } from 'react-easy-chart';
import getChartsData from '../../graphql/types/dashboards/getChartData'
import { VictoryChart, VictoryBar, VictoryTheme } from 'victory'

const ProjectWidget = (props) => {

    const projectName = props.match.params.ProjectName
    const dashboardName = props.match.params.dashboardName

    return (
        <Query query={getChartsData(projectName, dashboardName)}>
            {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                if (loading) return null;
                if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;
                return Object.values(data).map(element => {
                    console.log(element)
                    return element.map(item => {
                        console.log(item)
                        item.map(valueData => {
                            console.log(valueData)
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <FilterWidget />
                                    <div className="flex-container">
                                        <div className="flex-item flex-chart-item">
                                            <h1>Time allocated outside of active sprint</h1>
                                            <VictoryChart theme={VictoryTheme.material} domainPadding={1}>
                                                <VictoryBar style={{ data: { fill: "#ff00aa" } }} data={valueData.Chart.data} />
                                            </VictoryChart>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <Link to="/projects" className="btn btn-secondary">
                                        Back
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                    })
                });
            }}
        </Query>
    );
}

export default ProjectWidget;
```

I expect all elements to be rendered to the DOM.

Comment: have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: What's going on with that query? Why is a function being passed as if it's a child element? Also, this looks like the perfect code to do some refactoring: that nesting looks pretty crazy. Write some "renderXYZ" functions at the class level and call through to those in your arrow functions? Nesting arrow functions this much is a great way to lose track of where things actually return.

Comment: @Peter Yes, obviously. I also did further console logging as stated in my answer.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Will do. Main thing was getting it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change

```
return element.map(item => {
    console.log(item)
    item.map(valueData => {
```

to

```
return element.map(item => {
    console.log(item)
    return item.map(valueData => {
```